# SuiteScript 2.0 Suitelet Sublist with line-specific "Select" options

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I currently have a nice suitelet popup as a PDF Report selection. Everything so far works nicely.

However, some of the available PDF reports require individual options to be passed. ie. a date, or a class selction specific to ONLY 1 of the forms.

Currently I have created the sublist:

```
var documentList = form.addSublist({
    id: 'documentlist',
    label: 'Documents Available'+ (data.job ? ' for Job Number: '+data.job : ''),
    type: serverWidget.SublistType.LIST
})
documentList.addField({ id: 'mark',             type: 'CHECKBOX',       label: 'Print'});
documentList.addField({ id: 'config',           type: 'SELECT',         label: 'Form', source: 'customrecord_advancedformconfig' }).updateDisplayType({displayType : 'INLINE'});
documentList.addField({ id: 'vardate',          type: 'CHECKBOX',       label: 'Variation Dates' }).updateDisplayType({displayType : 'INLINE'});
documentList.addField({ id: 'document',         type: 'TEXT',           label: 'Document',  }).updateDisplayType({displayType : 'HIDDEN'});
documentList.addField({ id: 'primaryrecord',    type: 'TEXT',           label: 'Main Record'}).updateDisplayType({displayType : 'INLINE'});
documentList.addField({ id: 'storeincabinet',   type: 'CHECKBOX',       label: 'Save to Cabinet'}).updateDisplayType({displayType : 'INLINE'});
documentList.addField({ id: 'filename',         type: 'TEXT',           label: 'File Name to be Generated'}).updateDisplayType({displayType : 'NORMAL'});
var pdfOptions = documentList.addField({ id: 'formoption',  type: 'SELECT', label: 'Option' }).updateDisplayType({displayType : 'NORMAL'});
```

The last line is the sublist field for the form options.

Lets assume the first line requires a couple of date options, while the second line requires a couple of size or colour options.

As there is only a "field" action to `pdfOptions.addSelectOption(...)` this adds options to ALL occurences of the field.

Is there a method for each LINE of the sublist, to set options for just a single line??

There is no `pdfOptions.addSublistSelectOption(...)` so I'm going to guess the answer is not, but thought I would ask anyway.

To illustrate, see below image... Only the last line should have a date dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've accomplished having different select options for different lines is using a client script with the `lineInit` entry point that cleared out the existing options and added relevant ones for that line.

However you would need to change the sublist type from `LIST` to `EDITOR` or `INLINEEDITOR` for this to work, which probably wouldn't work well in your use case.